# See through material for IR camera

Tags: material-science, optical-materials

I have an IR camera that I'm trying to hide behind an opaque or fine meshed material (plastic?).

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What wavelength of IR does your camera work for? The best material will depend on that. If you don't know you could provide a link to the camera

Answer (score 1):

black plastic garbage/trash bags are quite transmissive of IR while being opaque in the visible. they are readily available and cheap too.

Answer (score 0):

Any sort of screen placed closed to the camera will be largely invisible to it. Yet it will appear almost opaque from far. That's the idea behind those drapes that are gauze, you can see out from them no problem, but people on the far side of the street can't see in.

Comment: What are the physics behind this? Is there any way I can calculate what the density of the filter should be?

Comment: Just buy a "privacy curtain" at a drape or fabric store, I'm pretty sure that it will work fine. The physics is basic diffraction - diffraction is an angle, so when the light is going into the camera it's only travelled maybe a few centimters and doesn't have much time to spread out, but going the other way it's across the room and has more time to spread.

Answer (score 0):

Infrared radiation spans over a wavelength-region of $700\,\mathrm{nm} – 1\,\mathrm{mm}$ and is often divided into **near-infrared** ($700\,\mathrm{nm} - 3\,\mathrm{\mu m}$), **mid-wavelength** infrared ($3\,\mathrm{\mu m} - 20\,\mathrm{\mu m}$), **far-infrared** ($20\,\mathrm{\mu m} - 10000\,\mathrm{\mu m}$) - note that the precise boundaries might vary.

Depending on the wavelength you are working with, different materials are (to a certain degree) transparent, a good example is **Polyethylene** often used for windows of IR cameras (which is non-transparent for visible light).